# Are the earlier expansions required for The Taken King?

Tags: destiny

Are "The Dark Below" and "House of Wolves" expansions required for playing "The Taken King"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes.**

> *What if I only own one of the two previous DLCs?*
>   You need both The Dark Below and House of Wolves to qualify for Destiny: The Taken King – Digital Edition (*[source](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/13072)*)

Here are the current ways of acquiring "The Taken King" :

- The $40 download of "The Taken King.", requiring previous DLC
- The $60 "Legendary Edition" including the original game and first two expansions, plus "The Taken King"
- The $80 "Collector's Edition"
- The $80 "Digital Collector's Edition"

(*[destinythegame.com](https://www.destinythegame.com/taken-king/wheretobuy)*)

Comment: Is there a version with only the DLCs? I already have the main game.

Comment: No, and fans have been quite disappointed.

Comment: Does the season pass not get you all the DLC?

Comment: @GnomeSlice the season pass gets you only the expansion 1 and expansion 2 without "The Taken King". You have to buy "The Taken King" extra!

Comment: @Oskar Given that the first 2 DLC's cost more than $20 combined, the Legendary Edition is still probably your best bet. ($40 of the Taken King standalone, plus $20 for DLC 1, DLC 2, and the other Legendary Edition goodies)

Comment: @SableDreamer That's right, and that's the problem. People shouldn't have to buy again a game they already own, should they ?

Comment: @Ealhad For someone who already had Expansions 1 & 2, I'd agree with you. But for someone who has *only* the base game, if they buy the Legendary edition, they're not *paying* for another copy of the base game (regardless of whether or not it is included in the bundle). People who _only_ need The Taken King, *are*.

Comment: @SableDreamer But why is the "Expansion Pass" + "TTK: Digital Edition" more expensive than "TTK: Legendary Edition"?

Comment: @Oskar Because capitalism? I don't set the prices, I just tell people how to maximize the value they get for their money, haha. The Expansion Pass is no longer current content, but its required for The Taken King, so I guess Bungie is okay with selling it for less if it encourages more people to buy The Taken King.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, yes, you need both "The Dark Below" and "House of Wolves" expansions to play "The Taken King".

Comment: Wow, Bungie has really found a way of sucking us dry. I ain't buying into their crap anymore.

Comment: @Wulfinite It's Activision-Blizzard -- this is the exact same model as WoW...